# Android studio cannot find aapt

Tags: android-studio, 32bit-64bit, aapt

Hi I am having trouble compiling, I get this error:

Gradle: Execution failed for task    ':ElectronicComponentInventorySearch:mergeDebugResources'.

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-   4.2.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

When I use locate:
   /opt/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt

Before I tried anything I made sure to chown the whole android-studio directory to my account and set permissions for everything to 775.

Whats up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android's aapt not running on 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10 (no ia32-libs). How can I fix this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523502/androids-aapt-not-running-on-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-no-ia32-libs-how-can-i-fix)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Aapt is a 32bit application. I am running ubuntu 64bit. I needed some additional libraries. First thing I did was update to 13.04 from 12.10. It broke chrome but [this should help](http://www.omgchrome.com/install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-13-10/).

To get aapt working (this fixed my issues with the avd as well) just run these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

From this [post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk)

Now no more problems.

Comment: @VasilValchev Since OP is specifically asking about a 32bit program on the 64bit OS - consider reposting as a new question.

Comment: What do I need for centos/yum?

Comment: Thanks.. without this my gradle never ended building the project

Comment: Solution works on Ubuntu 16.04 as well. I had migrated my entire project from one machine to another, manually mapped the sdk folder, still was getting the error like OP. This solution fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this :-

sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32z1-dev

Comment: This one did work for me, the accepted answer did not. Which is weird, given the number of +1 on the other answer. Anyway, problem solved, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Just open your Terminal & run this

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
```

Actually it was a architecture problem. **`Aapt`** expects `32` bit binaries and my system is `64` bits.

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio 0.3.7 on 64-bit Debian 7... this worked for me:

sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Building with Gradle is fine.  Debugging and running the emulator is fine (although still slow as usual).

Answer (score 0):

The package (32-bit) you are looking for is libbz2-1.0:i386, its 64-bit version is libbz2-1.0:amd64.

At first enable multi-arch support (if not done already):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can now install the package by:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```