# "aapt" IOException error=2, No such file or directory" why can't I build my gradle on jenkins?

Tags: java, android, jenkins, gradle, aapt

I have a little problem.

**The Problem:**
I am trying to build a gradle of my Android Project on Jenkins and now I am standing on this problem i can't resolve. 
During the Building I have this Error message:

```
:Client:mergeDebugResources
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/LMA-Client/Client/build/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/3.1.59/res/drawable-hdpi/common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png: 
Error: Cannot run program "/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/19.0.1/aapt": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
:Client:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

You can imagine that this aapt... yep its there and the png... its there too, so the mistake must be somewhere else.

**The Solution?**
Now I googled 1-2 hours around, surfed on this great Website and what I found is that if Jenkins runs on a 64-bit system, I need to install the ia32-libs. Like that:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

now I tried that, and I couldn't install it:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
```

so I tried to install *"ia32-libs-multiarch"*, but again:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Finally**
so finally im standing here and asking me: is that really the solution? And why should I install this thing? And how? So please help me, I think I am not far away from the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Cannot run aapt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041769/error-cannot-run-aapt)

Comment: @sschuberth No but its similar. The Solution in that other thread didn't work for me. A possible duplicate is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928164/android-studio-cannot-find-aapt/18930424#18930424

Answer (score 335, accepted):

I had the following similar error on Ubuntu 13.10:

`Cannot run program "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory`

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930424/514483) fixed it for me:

> To get aapt working (this fixed my issues with the avd as well) just install these two packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
> ```

Comment: That fixed the problem for me in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: That fixed it for me in Ubuntu 14.04 as well.

Comment: building chrome on Ubuntu 14.04 and this helped get me by the same error I was having with aapt.  Note ldd aapt now works, and shows dependencies.  Previously it stated that the program wasn't a dynamic executable "not a dynamic executable". Now on to the next problem!

Comment: Amen! also fix node exec aapt issues

Comment: Fixed my issue as well on Ubuntu 14.04, while running an ionic framework build.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it for me in Ubuntu 14.10. I presume it must require these 32 bit libraries which are not installed by default in 64 bit Ubuntu

Comment: In CentOS, these packages are non-existent.   yum install libstdc++-4.8.5-4.el7.i686  zlib.i686  .  That worked for me.

Comment: What about on a mac??

Comment: Use brew on mac for same packages

Comment: Confirmed this to be working on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 as well.

Comment: I had the same issue. Trying to execute `./aapt` manually returned "no such file or directory: ./aapt" (Zsh). This worked.

Answer (score 13):

For Arch 64 users, you must first [enable multilib](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multilib) for pacman, then install the 32-bit packages:

```
sudo pacman -Syv lib32-libstdc++5 lib32-zlib
```

Comment: Worked like a charm (4.16.13-2-ARCH), I  just had to replace my x64 image by x86 one

Answer (score 6):

For Fedora users:

```
sudo dnf install zlib.i686 libstdc++.i686
```

Comment: Thanks searching lot i got this answer and it works.

Comment: luckily my centos is just the same like fedora :)

Answer (score -2):

I installed *ndk* in the *sdk manager* and it worked.

Comment: SDK Manager -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> Checkbox "Android NDK" - 1.0.0 Installed.  I still get the OP's error.