# ProcessBuilder does not find the executable after moving to Spring Boot

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, spring-boot, external-process

I have a java class running as a task (as a plugin in an Java CMS) which used Quartz.
I am now moving it out of the CMS and into a Spring Boot (v1.0.2) project and am using @Scheduled annotation.

The problem i that the ProcessBuilder reports missing executable file, but a File().exist() return true.

It is the same Java version OpenJDK 7, same Application Container (Tomcat 7), on FreeBSD 9.2.

The testing code is a follow:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SchedulerTest {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=1800000, initialDelay=5000)
    public void test() {

        if ((new File("/usr/local/bin/exiftool")).exists()) {
            System.out.println("Found exiftool");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Did not find exiftool");
        }

        List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
        args.add("/usr/local/bin/exiftool");
        args.add("-n");
        args.add("-S");
        args.add("-DateTimeOriginal");
        args.add("/image/TEST.JPG");
        Process proc = null;
        try {
            proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (proc != null) {
            System.out.println("ExifTool output: " + proc.getOutputStream());
            proc.destroy();
        }
    }

}
```

The ouput is:

```
2014-04-28 12:30:49.471  INFO 22473 --- [ost-startStop-7] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 10.997 seconds (JVM running for 4022.804)
Found exiftool
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/bin/exiftool": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at no.hoanglai.service.SchedulerTest.test(SchedulerTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:184)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 14 more
```

What may be the problem?
My guessing is the move from Quartz to @Scheduled.
I have also tried to create cutsom bean and set the thread pool to 2, without any luck.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder` is a JDK utility, so I'd say this has nothing to do with Spring or `@Scheduled`. Is the file executable?

Comment: It seems so: ls -l /usr/local/bin/exiftool = -r-xr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  234426 Mar  3 10:07 /usr/local/bin/exiftool. I can run the command successfully in the shell as the same user as Tomcat is running as

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a file format problem (not really executable?). E.g. see here ["aapt" IOException error=2, No such file or directory" why can't I build my gradle on jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701405/aapt-ioexception-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory-why-cant-i-build-my-grad).