# gradlew build freezing at mergeDebugResources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew, gradle-plugin

I build debug app use gradlew as in google tutorial https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

I was created project use

```
android create project --target 2 -g -v 2.9--name myAppName --path ./MyAppDirectory --activity MyActivity --package com.mypackage
```

and this is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

buildTypes {
    release {
        //runProguard false
          //minifyEnabled true
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
}
```

I build debug app use command

```
$ ./gradlew assembleDebug
```

and building is freezing at 40% as

```
    :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/kanoonsantikul/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$Builder.start(AaptProcess.java:163)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:106)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 4 more
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/kanoonsantikul/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$Builder.start(AaptProcess.java:163)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:106)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
Thread(png-cruncher_5) has a null payload
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 4 more
Thread(png-cruncher_3) has a null payload
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/kanoonsantikul/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$Builder.start(AaptProcess.java:163)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:106)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 4 more
Thread(png-cruncher_2) has a null payload
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/kanoonsantikul/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$Builder.start(AaptProcess.java:163)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:106)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 4 more
Thread(png-cruncher_1) has a null payload
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/kanoonsantikul/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$Builder.start(AaptProcess.java:163)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:106)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:187)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 4 more
> Building 40% > :mergeDebugResources
```

`

Comment: Run the android sdk manager and install builds tools 23.0.2

Comment: I have the same issue, and build tools 23.0.2 is installed. The file about Gradle complains exists, so &#!!+@#!!!! >:( I can't imagine what the problem could be. It runs perfectly on my machine, and gives this error on the build server.

Comment: I came across the same problem, "... has a null payload" and the generic Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application. I uninstalled java/intellij, but only when I switched into build tools 27.0.0 did the issue get resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely you have a 64bit system and still some 32bits are missing for android development.

If you're running on a 64bit-Ubuntu system, see [32-bit-libs for Ubuntu 64-bit Android Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701405/aapt-ioexception-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory-why-cant-i-build-my-grad) for further details.

If you're running on a 64bit-Fedora system, see [installing-android-sdk-on-64-bit-fedora/](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8969/installing-android-sdk-on-64-bit-fedora/) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by installing the libraries

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1
>
> sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386