# react-native app starting failure

Tags: android, react-native

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpNow.png)

i trying to run react-native app on android simulator . i run the command react-native run-android . the app build starts. then after some time the process stops. it shows .

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$Builder.start(AaptProcess.java:167)
        at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:118)
        at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 4 more
Thread(png-cruncher_4) has a null payload
```

i can not understand how to solve the problem . can anyone help? thanks

Comment: I have 2 questions. 1. Did the project open on Android Studio ? 2. Did you run the app from expo or directly run the app on the simulator ?

Comment: no , i do not use expo.

Comment: no , the project is edited in VS code.. i do not use expo. react native cli

Comment: Can you just post one screenshot of how your files structure on android studio ? I guess something is wrong in the way you are building your project.

Comment: Have you installed the Android sdk's?

Comment: yes , i have installed sdk

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23201209/1066839