# Gradle aapt not a file

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, build-error

I try to build a android app with android studio. Gradle throws this error when i try to build:

> Gradle invocation completed successfully with 1 error(s) in 10 sec

and the message gradle build window shows:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':SlidingUpPanelLayout:processReleaseResources'.
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/[...]/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/19.0.2/aapt": error=2, No
>   such file or directory

but ls -l shows me this files:

```
~/development/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/19.0.2$ ls -l
total 49348
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david  1109734 Apr 12 12:29 aapt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david   271551 Apr 12 12:29 aidl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david  3570836 Apr 12 12:29 arm-linux-androideabi-ld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david    36534 Apr 12 12:29 bcc_compat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david   445402 Apr 12 12:29 dexdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david     2577 Apr 12 12:29 dx
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david  3570836 Apr 12 12:29 i686-linux-android-ld
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david     4096 Apr 12 12:29 lib
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david   332357 Apr 12 12:29 libbcc.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david   932160 Apr 12 12:29 libbcinfo.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david 15372369 Apr 12 12:29 libclang.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david 21101517 Apr 12 12:29 libLLVM.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david  1667769 Apr 12 12:29 llvm-rs-cc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david  1919720 Apr 12 12:29 mipsel-linux-android-ld
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    10800 Apr 12 12:29 NOTICE.txt
drwxr-xr-x 5 david david     4096 Apr 12 12:29 renderscript
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    16649 Apr 12 12:29 source.properties
```

why say gradle the the aapt is not a file? whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

this helped me [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928164/android-studio-cannot-find-aapt/18930424#18930424)

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```