# Android studio 1.0.2 not building app:mergeDebugResources error

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I just installed android studio on linux , configured the SDK and installed the building tools now when I try to sync with gradle or (build the app) it fails and throws this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   /home/user_name/AndroidStudioProjects/project_name/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/user_name/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
>   Error:Error: Cannot run program "/home/user_name/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
>   /home/user_name/AndroidStudioProjects/project_name/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png

I tried to change the ' buildToolsVersion ' in my gradle file and it gave me the same error for 21.1.2 , 1 , 0 also.

Comment: Make sure you're running the latest SDK. There was a bug that causes exactly this in 24.0.0.

Comment: @ScottBarta running **24.0.2**

Comment: Magic! How did you find that out?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I solved the problem by running those commands

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Ubuntu can't run the aapt on 64 bit before installing this packages

**EDIT 19-04-2016 :**

Android Studio 2 have the installation guide [updated](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools) with those packages and bunch more to compile on 64-bit machines correctly

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: Two days of frustration and finally this was the working solution.

Comment: Thanx a alot. it helped me too :-)

Comment: Thank you! This even removed the "R cannot be resolved" error, which, in my case, was not getting eliminated with any of the other suggested methods.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue even after trying out the accepted solution. In my case the gradle build tool version that I've specified was not installed on my debian system. It worked like a charm after I changed the buildToolVersion to the installed version which was (23.0.2)