# Android, build on Ubuntu fails due to aapt

Tags: android, ubuntu, jenkins

I am trying to build an Android project on a headless Ubuntu 14.04, but fail with the following error:

`> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/jenkins/AndroidSdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt''`

The stacktrace shows that the file has not been found, though the file is there. I googled it, and it turns out that this might happen if i try to execute a 32-bit file on a 64-bit architecture OS. However, it seems I have no control over which arch build tools are installed by `android sdk` utility. Is there any way I could get the 64 bit version?

Comment: Seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27589844/324262