# Unable to build, nor clean a naked single activity project in a newly installed Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've recently installed the newest stable version of Android Studio, on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. SDK been configured properly.

I created a single 'Activity' project from the blank Activity template, and made no changes to it.

When trying to build, or clean I get ***sporadically*** the followi:

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

That [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875648/android-studio-gradle-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution) to be [caused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114174/what-does-xxmaxpermsize-do/12114284#12114284) by VM's heap size. but adding `XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` only makes it occur fewer times, meaning, sometimes I don't get this error, without changing anything. 
so either its not the real solution, or 1024m is not enough (which doesn't seems right..)

However, when I don't get this error, build is still failing with:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
/home/a/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/a/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/a/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/a/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
/home/a/AndroidStudioProjects/useless/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png
Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/a/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/a/AndroidStudioProjects/useless/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/a/Android/Sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 13.341 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

witch is not really informative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, as strange is may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589844/android-studio-1-0-2-not-building-appmergedebugresources-error)  solves the problem (the second one). 
It's strange because there is no way to understand it from gradle outout.

Answer (score 6):

You have to install These Packages to Solve this Error Because Android SDK Still not working on UBUNTU 64 Bit.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 14.10[64 bits] & 15.04[64 bits] you can solved this problem and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32215821/3741698) problem with genymotion

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

**Good Luck!!**