# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just received this message now on my Android Studio:

**Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
Cause:
The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.**

, and I don't understand what it implies but I've tried restarting my Android studio, tried building and cleaning the project and I also tried solutions here [Android Studio Gradle failed to complete Gradle execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875648/android-studio-gradle-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution) , which I  couldn't find **Settings-->Gradle-->GradleVM options-->** on **Settings**.

Nothing worked so far, Does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: try invalidate caches and restart

Comment: How to I invalidate them?

Comment: File->Invalidate caches/Restart

Comment: if You will go to file then in drop down menu u will find invalidated cache option so u can do from that.

Comment: I just did now and still giving me the same message..

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it now... All I did was to update my Android Studio and the error message disappeared.